# Relationship between sequence SCNActions and SCNNodes

Tags: swift, ios8, core-animation, scenekit

What is the relationship between sequence actions, as e.g. created by `let sequence = SCNAction.sequence( [action1, action2] )` and `SCNNode`s?

Normally an association between an action and a node is made when `node.runAction(action)` is called. I assume that I should not call e.g. `node2.runAction(action2)`, because presumably this would run `action2` immediately and thus ignore its temporal dependency on `action1` in the sequence.

So is it the case that `node.runAction(sequence)` "implicitly" associates all actions in the sequence with the same node (i.e. `node`)? Or is it possible to run individual actions in a sequence on different nodes, and if so how?

**UPDATE** What I would like to accomplish is the following: Rotate `node1`, `node2`, and `node3` by 3 actions (i.e. a group action), then perform a move action on `node4` (further up in the hierarchy of nodes) when all rotations have completed (i.e. a sequence action)?

I am wondering about the specific sequence of (Swift) statements for starting which actions at which nodes at which times.

Answer (score 0):

actions are self-contained objects and are not tied to nodes. They operate on nodes but that node in only a variable when the action is executing. You can safely run the same actions on several nodes.

The result of sequencing actions is a new action, that you can perform on any node but during its execution it will operate one unique node (unless you use custom block-based action, that is).

Comment: So what sequence of statements do you use then for rotating `node1`, `node2`, `node3` in parallel (i.e. as group action) and then move `node4` when all rotations have finished (i.e. as sequence action)? Which actions do you start on what nodes and when?

Comment: there is no one right answer. You could write a block action that runs a rotate action on `node1` `node2` and `node3`, then group this action a wait action, and finally sequence the result with a move action and run everything on `node4`